# How can I sort posts in an shuffle mode in firebase, without repeat?

Tags: javascript, firebase, loops, shuffle

I want to show a list of the posts from a user following list.
I can show it in the default order, but I want to show it in a shuffle order.
I was using a function called shuffle, that works, but in my code doesn't work correctly, because repeat many posts.
My code is this:

```
function feed(){
var postList = document.getElementById('postList');
var userId = "a";

let rangeNumbers=[];

var keys = firebase.database().ref('users/'+userId).child("following").once('value').then(function(datakey){

        let usersPost = [];
    let usersPostProfile = [];
        var contador = 0;
    let htmlPost = "";
        var i = 0;

        datakey.forEach(function(data){

            let userDB = data.val();
            let userIdFollowing = userDB.id;

            firebase.database().ref('posts/').orderByChild("id").equalTo(userIdFollowing).once('value').then(function(postdatakey){

              let cantidad = postdatakey.numChildren();


         postdatakey.forEach(function(postdata){

            //Detecta todos los datos de la publicacion
            let postDB = postdata.val();
            let postId = postDB.id;



      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + postId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  let username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username);
  let name = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().name);
  let image = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().image);

  // ...
let newArray = {
            text: postDB.text,
            image: postDB.image,
            imageProfile: image,
            username: username,
            name: name,
            timestamp: postDB.timestamp
      };

 usersPost.push(newArray);

 htmlPost += 
      '<div class="postItem">'
      +'<br>'
    +'<img class="post-img-profile" src="'+usersPost[i].imageProfile+'">'
    +'<div class="userData">'

      +'<a><b>'+usersPost[i].name+'</b></a><br>'
      +'<a>'+usersPost[i].username+'</a>'
      +'</div>'
      +'<br><br><Br><br>'
      +'<div class="post">'
      +'<p>'+usersPost[i].text+'</p>'

      +'<div class="center-content">'
        +'<img class="imagePostBig" src="'+usersPost[i].image+'">'
      +'</div>'

    +'</div>'

    +'<div class="optionPost">'
      +'<img class="post-icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/like.png">'
    +'<img class="post-icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/comments.png">'
    +'<div class="line"></div>'
    +'</div>'



  +'</div>';

        //console.log(htmlPost);

        postList.innerHTML = htmlPost;

i++
      });


         });



            });  



                            });



    });  



}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}



feed();
```

I was using the shuffle function but it repeat the posts. Can you help me please? How can I show this post in a shuffle order?

Comment: Can you also post your HTML and put it all into a snippet so we can test it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell since I can't run it and you never actually call `shuffle` in the code you posted but it looks to me like you just need to call shuffle in the right place.

On the line before

`postdatakey.forEach(function(postdata){`

add

`shuffle(postdatakey);`

to randomize the order of the posts.